# Identrust X Google Cloud HSM X Electron Builder

Tags: electron, code-signing, electron-builder, hardware-security-module, ev-certificate

Hi I want to publish an app on the Microsoft store and this requires an EV certificate. I found that Identrust is the cheapest option, but I wanted to double check that they support using a cloud based HSM? So far I have only heard that Digicert and Sectigo support it, but they are 2x the price.

If not has anyone done it with their own yubikey?

I am using electron-builder if that matters.

Thanks!